# Printing the rest of the calendar month after the first week

Tags: java, eclipse, calendar, days

i am making a program that reads in the month 1-12 and the start day, 1-7 for sunday, monday, etc. it prints the first week fine but im having problems printing the rest of the days after the first week. it wont format the output to have a space between the rest of the days, only the first day after the first week.

side note: Keyboard is a class i have included in my project

heres my code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class CalendarMonth 
{
    static final int WEEK = 7;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        String proceed;
        char repeatCheck;
        int days;
        String leapYear;
        char leapYearCheck;
        int startDay;


        do
        {
            days = getDays();



            System.out.println(days);

            System.out.println("Please enter a number 1-7 that the month starts on: (1 for sunday, 2 for monday, etc)");
            startDay = Keyboard.readInt();


            while(startDay < 1 || startDay > 7)
            {
                System.out.println("You did not enter a number 1-7, Try again: ");
                startDay = Keyboard.readInt();
            }

            System.out.println(" s m t w th f sa");

            printMonth(days,startDay);


            System.out.println("\nWould you like to print another month?");
            proceed = Keyboard.readString();


            repeatCheck = proceed.charAt(0);


        }while(repeatCheck == 'y');
    }






    public static int getDays() throws IOException
    {
        int month;
        String leapYear;
        int startDay;
        int days = 0;
        char leapYearCheck;

        System.out.println("Please input a number 1-12 to print the corresponding month: ");
        month = Keyboard.readInt();
        while (month < 1 || month > 12)
        {
            System.out.println("You did not put a number 1-12, Try again: ");
            month = Keyboard.readInt();
        }

        switch(month)
        {
        case 1: days = 31;
        break;
        case 2: 

            System.out.println("is it a leap year? ");
            leapYear = Keyboard.readString();
            leapYearCheck = leapYear.charAt(0);

            while(leapYearCheck != 'y' && leapYearCheck != 'n')
            {
                System.out.println("you did not enter a yes or no answer, is it a leap year?");
                leapYear = Keyboard.readString();
                leapYearCheck = leapYear.charAt(0);
            }

            if (leapYearCheck == 'y')
            {
                days= 29;
            }
            else
            {
                days = 28;
            }

        break;
        case 3: days = 31;
        break;
        case 4: days = 30;
        break;
        case 5: days = 31;
        break;
        case 6: days = 30;
        break;
        case 7: days = 31;
        break;
        case 8: days = 31;
        break;
        case 9: days = 30;
        break;
        case 10: days = 31;
        break;
        case 11: days = 30;
        break;
        case 12: days = 31;
        break;
        }

        return days;
    }



    public static void printMonth(int days, int startDay)
    {
        int count;

        count = startDay;
        for (int counter = 1; counter <= 7; counter++)
        {
            if (counter < startDay)
            {
                System.out.print("  ");
                count = count-1;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.printf("%2d", count);

                count++;
            }
        }

        //int restOfTheMonth = (WEEK - startDay);


        System.out.println();
            for(int restOfTheMonth = count; restOfTheMonth <= days; restOfTheMonth++)
            {

                if (restOfTheMonth%WEEK==0)
                {
                    System.out.println();
                }
                System.out.printf("%2d", restOfTheMonth);

            }



    }


}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: ive ran the debugger inside of eclipse but that doesnt do anything...the program runs fine i just need help printing the rest of the month

Comment: Using a debugger you will understand why `it wont format the output to have a space between the rest of the days, only the first day after the first week.`